# monacaでプッシュ通知の差別化

Tags: monaca

monacaでプッシュ通知機能を実装するにあたり、プッシュ通知を小分けすることはできますか？
例えば
ユーザーAはAコンテンツコンテンツのプッシュ通知がほしいがBコンテンツは不要
逆にユーザーBはコンテンツAはいらないがコンテンツBのプッシュ通知が必要

このように一つのアプリでコンテンツごとにトグルを設置し、通知をオンにしているユーザーにだけプッシュ通知を行うことは可能でしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: NiftyのmBaaSなら、こちらを参照してください。コミュニティにも関連した内容が記載されていますので、まずは調査することが必要かと思います。http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/push/filter_monaca.html

Comment: ありがとうござます！
とても助かります